# Adding jQuery script to wordpress custom page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

trying to incorporate a jQuery script into a Wordpress site.

I created a custom page in my theme and added the following in the body tag:

```
<body>
...
<div id="msgid"> hello there
</div>
...
</body>
```

I also created a test.js file with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#msgid").html("Hello world.");
});
```

I am loading the test.js in the footer.

I was expecting to see Hello world. in the div. But it doesn't show anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wordpress by default uses the noConflict version of jQuery, which means it doesn't load jQuery to the $ sign.

You can do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   //inside of here you passed in the $ sign to be used as an alias of jQuery
   $("#msgid").html("Hello world.");
});
```

See here for more details on jQuery's noConflict function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: thanks. Do I have to use function($) or can I use function() and use jQuery("#msgid") instead of $("#msgid")? Thanks.

Comment: @jdias You can use jQuery("#msgid") as well. The important thing to understand here is that by passing in the $ into function, you're essentially assigning jQuery to $. So imagine this is happening: $ = jQuery.